# Deadline for resubmission in Physical Review E

Tags: journals, peer-review, physics

As the title suggests, does anyone what is a typical deadline for the resubmission in the mentioned journal? As it was not specified anywhere.

Comment: Consider asking the journal staff.

Comment: Or the editor who handled your paper. That's that person's job: to help you with these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only published in other Physical Review journals, but I'm not sure they have a hard deadline. If there is, it's never been communicated to me anyway. As written in the comments, the best way to know for sure would be asking the journal staff or the editor... As a semi-relevant anecdote, I was once quite slow in finishing a minor revision for PRB, and the editors asked me about the status of the paper after roughly one and a half months. They then accepted me saying that it'll be resubmitted in two weeks.

Generally, if you have long delays (think over one month) - especially if there's decent justification for it - I think the journal will be happy to work with you if you communicate this to them.